# 'Vector3?' does not contain a definition for 'x' and no accessible extension method 'x' accepting a first argument of type 'Vector3?'

Tags: vector

I keep getting this error, any idea why?

```
 if (postion.x - newPos.x < 150)
            {
                doThis();
            }
```